# Which shell configuration files are read for the shell started with "sudo -i"?

Tags: bash, sudo, bashrc

According to `man sudo` `sudo -i` starts a login shell and should in my understanding read/source `~/.profile`, i.e. `/root/profile` or `[non-root user home/.profile` and `/etc/profile`. Adding aliases, e.g. `alias ll='ls -la'` to both files doesn't make the alias available in the shell started by `sudo -i`. If I run `bash` in the shell stared by `sudo -i` aliases are available.

I already figured out to put aliases in `/etc/profile.d/00-aliases.sh` in https://askubuntu.com/questions/810730/how-to-share-bash-aliases-between-non-root-user-bash-and-shell-opened-by-sudo. Here I just want to know why the expected behaviour doesn't occur.

I reported this as [a sudo bug on launchpad.net](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/sudo/+bug/1612028), but now I'm not sure whether this might be a tricky aspect of expected behaviour. The way `man sudo` describes `-i` is too trivial anyway.

Comment: sudo: `-i: Run the shell specified by the target user's password database entry as a login shell.` bash: `A login shell is one whose first character of argument zero is a -, or one started with the --login option.` sudo just sets the dash as the first character in the shell's name when running it.

Comment: the complete description for Bash's startup files is [in the manual, here](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Bash-Startup-Files). It's a bit hard to find out what the exact problem with the aliases would be without seeing _all_ of your `/root/.*{profile,login}` and `/etc/profile*`. And the `bashrc` files.

Answer (score 0):

The files that are read depends on the target user's shell.  So, for example, if you `sudo -u user1 -i` and user1 uses `csh` then it'll read `~user1/.login`.   For ksh users it would be `~user1/.profile`.

For `bash` users (like `root`) the file read is `~/.bash_profile` if it exists, with a fallback to `~/.profile`

eg

```
% sudo head -1 /root/.bash_profile /root/.profile 
==> /root/.bash_profile <==
echo RUNNING BASH_PROFILE

==> /root/.profile <==
echo RUNNING PROFILE

% sudo -i
RUNNING BASH_PROFILE
root@server:~# rm /root/.bash_profile
root@server:~# exit
logout

% sudo -i
RUNNING PROFILE
root@server:~#
```

So we can see the presence of `.bash_profile` prevented `.profile` from being run.  This is normal behaviour for `bash` login shells, whether it's accessed via a ssh login or via `sudo -i`.

Comment: Now, I got it. `/root/.profile` is only sourced at the first `sudo -i` after reboot (or maybe display manager (re-)login), not at every following `sudo -i` - at least in `gnome-terminal`. If `sudo -i` is run once when `/root/.bash_profile` is present it is sourced (and `/root/.profile` skipped as expected) and if it `/root/.bash_profile` is removed every following invokation of `sudo -i` causes `/root/.profile` to be sourced. That not right, right?